# Getting incompatible pointer type error while working with structs

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I am writing a program with in which I have to create a list of employees and work with the information in it. In the `writeToFile` I write the info. to a `.txt` file. In the `newList` I should create a new list, which will contain employees which match certain criteria. However, when I intiliaze `*newListHead` pointer I get `initialization of 'newEmployeeList *' {aka 'struct newEmployeeList *'} from incompatible pointer type 'List *' {aka 'struct List *'} [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]|` error. What am I doing wrong since I did the same thing for the `head` pointer?

```
typedef struct employee {
    char name[20];
    double salary;
    char gender[10];
} employee;

typedef struct List {
    employee info;
    struct List *next;
} List;

typedef struct newEmployeeList {
    employee info;
    struct newEmployeeList *next;
} newEmployeeList;

List *create_new_node() {
    List *new_node = NULL;
    new_node = (List*)malloc(sizeof(List));
    new_node->next = NULL;
    return new_node;
};

int main()
{
    List *head = create_new_node();
    writeToFile("test.txt", head);

    newEmployeeList *newListHead = create_new_node();
    newList(head, newListHead);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you have a separate `List` and `newEmployeeList` which are exactly equivalent aside from the name?

Comment: `List` and `newEmployeeList` are two different types.  You should only have one type for both.  Just get rid of the `newEmployeeList` type and use `List` in its place.

Comment: I have to create a new struct, because that's a requirement from the professor. I can't change it. @AKX

Comment: @zaro A new *type* of struct, or a new *instance* of an existing struct?

Comment: @dbush new list, which will contain only certain employees

Comment: @zaro That sounds like a new instance, in which case you can use `List` for both lists.

Comment: @dbush Yea, I think I can do it with just a new pointer; but thank you for clarifying the error message!

Answer (score 1):

As the error message says, the `create_new_node` function is returning a `List *` but you're assigning that value to a `newEmployeeList *`.  Those types are incompatible.

Either change the type of `newListHead` to `List *` or create a different function that returns a new instance of `newEmployeeList *`.  I'd recommend the former as there's no reason to even have the type `newEmployeeList` from what you've shown.

Comment: Thank you. The reasno to have `newEmployeeList` is becuase it is a requirement from the professor.